# Comparing "queries" and then saving the result for new select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Iam trying to make a query that will check if a user is logged in or not. 
The data is stored as 2 seperate rows one is called "in", when a users logs in and the other "out". I then need to find all people currently logged in but not logged out. so what ive tried is comparing the two select statement. This gives me the name(UNILOGIN) of all the people currently logged in and not out:

```
select UNILOGIN from timereg where date = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),110) and CHECKEDIN = 'IND'
except
select UNILOGIN from timereg where date = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),110) and CHECKEDIN = 'UD'
```

I then need to find their top 1 time, when they checked in. How would one make a statement that could get result in in one query string? If possible at all. something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 UNILOGIN, TIME from TIMEREG where UNILOGIN = "result of query"
```

Tell me if i need to elaborate.

Comment: Why do you need `CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),110)`? Isn't `date` a date? Looks like a poor table design then.

Comment: Why do you expect to find several login records per `unilogin` (where you want to find the top one) and no logout records? Can users login again and again without logging out?

Comment: Depends on the application doing the logging. The logout process might not fire for some reasons and you'll never see a logout row. Just a thought of why there might be no logouts.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah users can login and can logout multiple times a day, lets just say that they are going to the dentist, and then logging back in.

Comment: So why do you look for users without a logout then? Isn't it such that they *can* have logouts and still being logged in? (Namely when they have one logout less than logins.)

Comment: Is the data type conversion simply an attempt to remove the time part in the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate. Get one result row per `unilogin`, make sure it has an 'IND' record and no 'UD' record and select the maximum login time for the date in question.

```
select unilogin, max(time)
from timereg 
where date = convert(date, getdate(), 110) 
and checkedin in ('IND', 'UD')
group by unilogin 
having count(case when checkedin = 'IND' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when checkedin = 'UD' then 1 end) = 0;
```

Comment: getting: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'. At line 6

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the column names in the case expressions. I've corrected this.

Comment: And I suspect you should rather be looking out for `having count(case when checkedin = 'IND' then 1 end) > count(case when checkedin = 'UD' then 1 end)`, i.e. more logins than logouts. See our discussion about logouts in the request's comment section on this.

Comment: Ive used your code in the last comment, and it gave me what i needed(ish). Though i need to get the info from "TIME" to see when was their last login, that is were it gets somewhat tricky because then the rows arent the same. :-)

Comment: Inserted max(time), and it worked thanks to you. thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Yes, `max(date)` made no sense of course. That was a careless mistake.